# Display multiple images, one after the other, in an image ActiveX in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I need to display a series of pictures, about 58 pieces, in an Image ActiveX control in Excel.

If I press a button, it should play the images one after the other like a GIF.
We cannot use gifs.

I'm a bit weak in loops.

```vb
Sub Button3_Click()
Dim x As Integer

x = 1

ActiveSheet.Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\Irene\" & x & ".jpg")

'MsgBox (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\Irene\" & x & ".jpg")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Sub main()
    Dim iPic As Long

    With ActiveSheet.Image1
        For iPic = 1 To 6
            .Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\Irene\" & iPic & ".jpg")
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

In my coding for such things I also use a sort of "timer" to let pictures be shown:

```
Sub main()
    Dim iPic As Long

    With ActiveSheet.Image1
        For iPic = 1 To 6
            .Picture = LoadPicture(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Images\Irene\" & iPic & ".jpg")
            MyWait '<--| added to let pictures be actually shown one by one
        Next
    End With
End Sub

Sub MyWait()
    Dim time1, time2

    time1 = Now
    time2 = Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
    Do Until time1 >= time2
        DoEvents
        time1 = Now()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: so to clarify , this line (For iPic = 1 To 6) is the number of pictures I have? and how do I make the pictures display so fast, I mean like a GIF file, the above code displays them slowly, what value should I use for TimeValue

Comment: 1) yes, number 6 in my code is the number of pictures you have. 2) the displaying speed in my code is tuned by `MyWait()` sub through `+TimeValue("0:00:01")` part of the `time2` assignment statement, which is currently 1 second. To make it faster you have to search for a different method than mine that handles time amounts smaller than 1 second (for example, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470632/vba-show-clock-time-with-accuracy-of-less-than-a-second))

Comment: @danjok, since I answered your question about how to loop through images, you may want to accept it. thank you